# Scala how to extract substring in URL and create a new column for it?

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe

In Scala dataframe, assume one of the column is a URL string, formatted like:
https://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/o-5+t-1858+d-8011 OR https://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/t-1858+d-8011, what is the best way to extract the information after "t-", in this case, "1858" and create a new column for this data?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above URL data you can use the following regex and extract the value '1858' (assuming always a number to be extracted):

```
val urlDataRegex = "http.*t-(\\d++).*".r
```

If for example if you are holding a sample URL data:

```
val sampleData = "https://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/o-5+t-1858+d-8011"
```

*By using the regular expression you can extract the number and assign it to a variable as follows:*

```
val urlDataRegex(urlData) = sampleData
```

The variable 'urlData' will have the value '1858'. If for any reason the data was not like as expected you would get a MatchError exception been thrown.